# Adding messages to HandlerThread's Queue from Ui Thread's onSensorChanged() method

Tags: android

```
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

        if(seekBar.getId() == R.id.seekBar)
        {
            speed.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
            String outputData = speed.getText().toString()+","+"hey"+","+"hell"+";";

            if(streams.getOutputStream() != null && wtHandler != null)
            {
                wtHandler.sendMessage(wtHandler.obtainMessage(9999, outputData)); //wtHandler is Handler for HandlerThread's Looper

            }
            else
            {
                Log.d("RTR", "handler of output stream null");
            }
        }
```

I'm using a `HandlerThread` to send data via bluetooth.The code above transmits data when `SeekBar` is changed and its working.

When I perform the above transmission from `onSensorChanged()` method,it doesn't work.Code below.

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
        {
            float accXYZ[] = event.values;

            float accX = accXYZ[0];
            float accY = accXYZ[1];
            float accZ = accXYZ[2];

            x.setText(String.format("%.2f",accX));
            y.setText(String.format("%.2f",accY));
            z.setText(String.format("%.2f",accZ));

            //String outputData = x.getText().toString()+","+speed.getText().toString()+";";
            String outputData = x.getText().toString()+";";

            if(wtHandler != null && wtHandler.getOutputStream() != null)   //add output stream null later
            {

                wtHandler.sendMessageDelayed(wtHandler.obtainMessage(9999,outputData),10);
                Log.d("RTR","Added message to the Queue");
            }
            else if(wtHandler == null)
            {
                Log.d("RTR","Worker Thread Handler not created yet");
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d("RTR","OP Stream null");
            }
```

What might be the problem? I suspect its the rate at which onSensorChanged() is getting called.All the above code is running in UI Thread and i'm just adding messages to `HandlerThread'`s `Looper` `Queue` from here.

Your thoughts please

Comment: Are you sure that your onSensorChanged method is getting called ? and that getOutputStream doesn't return null ?

Comment: @Mr.Me Yeah."Adding message to the Queue" is printed in Logcat.

Comment: And the handler that gets called in both onProgressChanged and onSensorChanged is the same ?

Comment: @Mr.Me The handler implementation is same but these two are from different applications.Both the applications are same except for this part

Comment: can you please post all related code ? ( Handler class and Sensor registering code )

Comment: @Mr.Me Indeed the problem is with speed.I slowed down the rate at which messages are being added to the Looper Queue and everything is fine now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This how I changed the rate at which messages are being added to the Queue and everything works fine now

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
        {
            float accXYZ[] = event.values;

            float accX = accXYZ[0];
            float accY = accXYZ[1];
            float accZ = accXYZ[2];

            x.setText(String.format("%.2f",accX));
            y.setText(String.format("%.2f",accY));
            z.setText(String.format("%.2f",accZ));

            try {
                //String outputData = x.getText().toString()+","+speed.getText().toString()+";";
                String outputData = x.getText().toString()+","+speed.getText().toString()+";";

                if( workerThread.getWtHandler() != null && workerThread.getWtHandler().getOutputStream() != null)   //add output stream null later
                {
                    if(System.currentTimeMillis() - time > 50)
                    {
                        workerThread.getWtHandler().sendMessage(workerThread.getWtHandler().obtainMessage(9999, outputData));
                        Log.d("RTR","Added message to the Queue");
                    }
                }
                else if(workerThread.getWtHandler() == null)
                {
                    Log.d("RTR","Worker Thread Handler not created yet");
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.d("RTR","OP Stream in Handler null");
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.d("RTR","Worker Thread not created yet");
            }
            time = System.currentTimeMillis();
```